# Несколько пулов PHP-FPM на 1 сайт

Tags: php-fpm, оптимизация-сайтов

Правильно ли я понимаю, что у 1 сайта должно запускаться несколько пулов php-fpm? У нас после установки NGINX + PHP-FPM на каждый сайт запускается несколько пулов, при том с одним именем (php-fpm: pool website-php-fcgi-0), от одного юзера (www-datа), но с разными PID. И они все кушают оперативку)) Вопрос: правильно ли это или стоит перенастроить конфиг так, чтобы на 1 сайт был 1 пул?? Сайт простой без интерактива с пользователем.

Comment: Вы путаете пулы и процессы. Один файл www.conf запускает один пул процессов. Этот пул может обслуживать любое количество сайтов. А несколько процессов нужны для того, чтобы эффективно обрабатыаать несколько параллельных запросов к вашему сайту.

Comment: Спасибо, значит все в порядке до определенной степени